# Type Object created with destructured Object and spread operator

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I want to type `foo` which I created like this:

```
interface IFoo {
  b: number;
  c: number;
}
interface IBar {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
}
const bar: IBar = { a: 1, b: 2, c:3 };
const { a, ...foo } = bar;
```

I saw on other SO posts, that I could solve it like this:

```
const { a, ...foo }: { a: number, foo: IFoo } = bar;
```

But then I get following Typescript Error:

> TS2322: Type 'IBar' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; foo: IFoo; }'.
>     Property 'foo' is missing in type 'IBar'.

I came up with the following solution:

`const typedFoo: IFoo = foo;`

now I can use typedFoo as a typed object instead of foo - but this I deem inelegant.

Comment: You can type individual destructured members with the annotation, but `...foo` is not a generate a member `foo` in the result. Don't think we can type the rest part

Comment: rest parameter can not be typed as @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir mentioned. so your approach is right of doing const typedFoo: IFoo = foo;